# "[RequireComponent (typeof(ScriptName))]" inside a namespace?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

> error CS1730: Assembly and module attributes must precede all other elements defined in a file except using clauses and extern alias declarations

As it says the code does have 1 attribute inside the namespace above the class, it is `[RequireComponent (typeof(Text))]` for a text element for dialogue. See also [RequireComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RequireComponent.html)

Why is it giving me this error? i cannot place it outside the namespace, so am i required to simply remove the namespace? that seems pretty inconvenient.. as codes would conflict is i didnt have them in namespaces... whats the go-around?

Code below:

```cs
using UnityEngine;   
using UnityEngine.UI;

namespace ZeredaGamesEngine.Core.Libraries.Games.Quests   
{
  [RequireComponent (typeof(Text))]   
  public class DialogueManager : MonoBehaviour   
  {   
     string Text textComponent;   

     public string[] sentences;   
  }

}
```

Comment: That error is not caused by a class-level attribute. Look for `[assembly: SomeAttribute]` or possibly `[module: SomeAttribute]`. Maybe in a `.designer.cs` file? The compiler should tell you which file and line.

Comment: solved by restarting the editor. not sure why i was getting that error forgot about this question. it is solved though.